# OpenXML Spreadsheet: Excel gives an error, then mends it and it works. (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I narrowed it down to:

```
       //aantal auto's
        Row aantalAutosRow = new Row();
        aantalAutosRow.RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32((tblXML.Rows.Count) + 2);

        Cell aantalAutosCell = new Cell();
        aantalAutosCell.CellReference = getColumnName(1);
        aantalAutosCell.CellValue = new CellValue("Hoi");

        aantalAutosRow.Append(aantalAutosCell);
        sheetData.Append(aantalAutosRow);
```

This generates the Cell after I click yes when Excel prompts to fix the file (sheet.xml)

Complete class:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
            using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
            using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Xml;
            using System.Data;

            namespace XML_naar_Excel
            {
                class Excel
                {
                    public void convertToExcel(string padXml)
                    {
                        //maak dataset en vul met ingevoerde xml
                        DataSet dsXML = new DataSet();
                        dsXML.ReadXml(padXml);
                        DataTable tblXML = dsXML.Tables[2];

                        //opslaan
                        string padXlsx = Path.GetDirectoryName(padXml) + "\\voorraad " + DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + ".xlsx";

                        //spreadsheet
                        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(padXlsx, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                        {
                            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                            FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
                            fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
                            Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();
                            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

                            //styles
                            Style s = new Style();
                            WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                            stylesPart.Stylesheet = s.GenerateStyleSheet();
                            stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

                            //kolommen
                            Columns columns = new Columns();
                            for (int i = 1; i < tblXML.Columns.Count; i++)
                            {
                                Column column = new Column();
                                column.Min = Convert.ToUInt32(i);
                                column.Max = Convert.ToUInt32(i + 1);
                                int lengte = tblXML.Rows[13][i-1].ToString().Length;
                                if (lengte < 10)
                                {
                                    lengte = 10;
                                }
                                else if (lengte > 35)
                                {
                                    lengte = 35;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    lengte += 5;
                                }
                                column.Width = lengte;
                                column.BestFit = true;
                                columns.Append(column);
                            }
                            worksheet.Append(columns);

                            //header
                            Row header = new Row();
                            header.RowIndex = (UInt32)1;

                            foreach (DataColumn columnInDataTable in tblXML.Columns)
                            {
                                Cell headerCell = createTextCell(tblXML.Columns.IndexOf(columnInDataTable) + 1, 1, columnInDataTable.ColumnName);
                                headerCell.StyleIndex = 1;
                                header.AppendChild(headerCell);
                            }
                            sheetData.AppendChild(header);

                            // Add a row to the cell table.
                            for (int i = 1; i < tblXML.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                Row row;
                                row = new Row() { RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(i) + 1 };

                                for (int j = 0; j < tblXML.Columns.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    Cell newCell = new Cell()
                                    {
                                        CellReference = getColumnName(i),
                                        DataType = CellValues.String,
                                        StyleIndex = 6,
                                        CellValue = new CellValue(tblXML.Rows[i][j].ToString()),
                                    };
                                    row.Append(newCell);
                                }
                                sheetData.Append(row);
                            }

                            //autofilter
                            string laatsteKolom = zoekLaatsteKolom(tblXML);
                            AutoFilter autoFilter = new AutoFilter();
                            autoFilter.Reference = "A1:" + laatsteKolom + "1";

                            //aantal auto's
                            Row aantalAutosRow = new Row();
                            aantalAutosRow.RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32((tblXML.Rows.Count) + 2);

                            Cell aantalAutosCell = new Cell();
                            aantalAutosCell.CellReference = getColumnName(1);
                            aantalAutosCell.CellValue = new CellValue("Hoi");
                            //CellFormula berekenAantalAutos = new CellFormula();
                            //berekenAantalAutos.Text = "=COUNTA(A2:A" + tblXML.Rows.Count.ToString();

                            //aantalAutosCell.Append(berekenAantalAutos);
                            aantalAutosRow.Append(aantalAutosCell);
                            sheetData.Append(aantalAutosRow);

                            worksheet.Append(sheetData);
                            worksheet.Append(autoFilter);
                            worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
                            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
                            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
                            sheet.Name = "Voorraad";
                            sheet.SheetId = 1;
                            sheet.Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
                            sheets.Append(sheet);
                            workbook.Append(fv);
                            workbook.Append(sheets);

                            spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
                            spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    //kolom naam (letter) ophalen
                    private string getColumnName(int columnIndex)
                    {
                        int dividend = columnIndex;
                        string columnName = String.Empty;
                        int modifier;

                        while (dividend > 0)
                        {
                            modifier = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                            columnName =
                                Convert.ToChar(65 + modifier).ToString() + columnName;
                            dividend = (int)((dividend - modifier) / 26);
                        }

                        return columnName;
                    }

                    private Cell createTextCell(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, object cellValue)
                    {
                        Cell cell = new Cell();

                        cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
                        cell.CellReference = getColumnName(columnIndex) + rowIndex;

                        InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
                        Text t = new Text();

                        t.Text = cellValue.ToString();
                        inlineString.AppendChild(t);
                        cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

                        return cell;
                    }

                    string zoekLaatsteKolom(DataTable tblXML)
                    {
                        string kolom;
                        kolom = getColumnName(tblXML.Columns.Count);
                        return kolom;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing that is illegal to Excel? I think excel makes SharedStrings when mending it. I never worked with SharedStrings and I hope I don't have to.

Comment: You can try downloading OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425 if you load your generated file into the Productivity Tool in many cases it can tell you what is illegal in your generated file.

Answer (score 3):

I went through your code and found 4 places that needed change in order to generate a fault-free excel document.

1. Replaced `stylesPart.Stylesheet = s.GenerateStyleSheet();`
 by `stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();`

2. Commented out the following  : `//headerCell.StyleIndex = 1;`

3. Commented out the following : `//StyleIndex = 6,`

4. Added the following : `aantalAutosCell.DataType = CellValues.String;`

The code posted below works for me and generates an error free excel document.
Few pointers you need to know

1. You cannot arbitrarily assign style indices when working with Open XML Docs

2.  When ever you have a string data type to be stored you should use CellValues.String (since you don't want to use Shared String)

3. It's really worth while to read about SharedStrings when working with Open XML SDK. Shared Strings reduce the overall size of your file and make things so much better. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278314.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace TestOpenXmlSDK
{
    class Excel
    {
        public void convertToExcel(string padXml)
        {
            //maak dataset en vul met ingevoerde xml
            DataSet dsXML = new DataSet();
            dsXML.ReadXml(padXml);
            DataTable tblXML = dsXML.Tables[2];

            //opslaan
            string padXlsx = Path.GetDirectoryName(padXml) + DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + ".xlsx";

            //spreadsheet
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(padXlsx, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
                fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
                Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

                //styles
                WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

                //kolommen
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Columns columns = new Columns();
                for (int i = 1; i < tblXML.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Column column = new Column();
                    column.Min = Convert.ToUInt32(i);
                    column.Max = Convert.ToUInt32(i + 1);
                    int lengte = tblXML.Rows[13][i - 1].ToString().Length;
                    if (lengte < 10)
                    {
                        lengte = 10;
                    }
                    else if (lengte > 35)
                    {
                        lengte = 35;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lengte += 5;
                    }
                    column.Width = lengte;
                    column.BestFit = true;
                    columns.Append(column);
                }
                worksheet.Append(columns);

                //header
                Row header = new Row();
                header.RowIndex = (UInt32)1;

                foreach (DataColumn columnInDataTable in tblXML.Columns)
                {
                    Cell headerCell = createTextCell(tblXML.Columns.IndexOf(columnInDataTable) + 1, 1, columnInDataTable.ColumnName);
                    //headerCell.StyleIndex = 1;
                    header.AppendChild(headerCell);
                }
                sheetData.AppendChild(header);

                // Add a row to the cell table.
                for (int i = 1; i < tblXML.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Row row;
                    row = new Row() { RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(i) + 1 };

                    for (int j = 0; j < tblXML.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Cell newCell = new Cell()
                        {
                            CellReference = getColumnName(i),
                            DataType = CellValues.Number,
                            //StyleIndex = 6,
                            CellValue = new CellValue(tblXML.Rows[i][j].ToString()),
                        };
                        row.Append(newCell);
                    }
                    sheetData.Append(row);
                }

                //autofilter
                string laatsteKolom = zoekLaatsteKolom(tblXML);
                AutoFilter autoFilter = new AutoFilter();
                autoFilter.Reference = "A1:" + laatsteKolom + "1";

                //aantal auto's
                Row aantalAutosRow = new Row();
                aantalAutosRow.RowIndex = Convert.ToUInt32((tblXML.Rows.Count) + 2);

                Cell aantalAutosCell = new Cell();
                aantalAutosCell.CellReference = getColumnName(1);
                aantalAutosCell.CellValue = new CellValue("Hoi");
                aantalAutosCell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                //CellFormula berekenAantalAutos = new CellFormula();
                //berekenAantalAutos.Text = "=COUNTA(A2:A" + tblXML.Rows.Count.ToString();

                //aantalAutosCell.Append(berekenAantalAutos);
                aantalAutosRow.Append(aantalAutosCell);
                sheetData.Append(aantalAutosRow);

                worksheet.Append(sheetData);
                worksheet.Append(autoFilter);
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
                sheet.Name = "Voorraad";
                sheet.SheetId = 1;
                sheet.Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
                sheets.Append(sheet);
                workbook.Append(fv);
                workbook.Append(sheets);

                spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
                spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }
        }

        //kolom naam (letter) ophalen
        private string getColumnName(int columnIndex)
        {
            int dividend = columnIndex;
            string columnName = String.Empty;
            int modifier;

            while (dividend > 0)
            {
                modifier = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                columnName =
                    Convert.ToChar(65 + modifier).ToString() + columnName;
                dividend = (int)((dividend - modifier) / 26);
            }

            return columnName;
        }

        private Cell createTextCell(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, object cellValue)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
            cell.CellReference = getColumnName(columnIndex) + rowIndex;

            InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
            Text t = new Text();

            t.Text = cellValue.ToString();
            inlineString.AppendChild(t);
            cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

            return cell;
        }

        string zoekLaatsteKolom(DataTable tblXML)
        {
            string kolom;
            kolom = getColumnName(tblXML.Columns.Count);
            return kolom;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Isrchckn : If this code worked for you, please mark it as answer.